# I cannot seem to download/install the carousel_slider package through pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

i have ran flutter pub get multiple times but I'm still not able to download the carousel_slider package

So far I've tried:

Running flutter clean

Running flutter packages get

Running flutter packages get

Restarting my computer

Updated flutter

Tried opening it in VSCode instead

Added another package (but that did install, I could see it in the Dart Packages)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see that is working well, but you can try deleting the pubspect.lock

In the terminal write this commands:

- flutter clean
- flutter packages get

Comment: I've tried this also multiple times, including flutter upgrade, restarting my ide, I even updated the IDE's dart and flutter plugins but it still doesn't work!!

Comment: can you upload a short video